# Adding months to timestamp in PHP

Tags: php

```
        $bought_months = 6;
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $expiring = strtotime('+'.$bought_months.' month', $currentDate);
```

This is what i tried.

I am trying to get a unix timestamp value of 6 months ahead from today.

How can i add months to my unix timestamp right? I tried above, since my other thought - calculating by seconds like one month in seconds: 2 629 743.83 * how many months + current timestamp, will not be precise.

(ofcourse because months have different number of days)

I get "A non well formed numeric value encountered" for the code above.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the current timestamp, you can omit the `$currentDate` variable altogether and it should make the notice go away too.

```
    $bought_months = 6;
    $expiring = strtotime('+'.$bought_months.' month');
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the date correctly you'd need to use something like:

```
mktime( 0, 0, 0, ( $month + 6 ), $day, $year );
```

Answer (score 2):

For maximum compatibility with post-2038 dates, use php's builtin DateTime class:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->modify("+6 months");
echo $d->format("U");
```